# Open and display image selected from local folder

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm a new learner in Python and I wanted to create a simple program where a user can open and display an image (png) selected from local folder.

```
def imageopen():

        root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                                   filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        print(root.filename)


    button = Button(text="Open Image", width=30, command=imageopen).pack()
```

So I have the code above to select any image from local, and it returns the path of the image back as result. My question is, how can I use the path to display the image?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Relevant [how-to-show-an-image-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212405/how-to-show-an-image-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pillow for this comes pre-installed in anaconda. Simply do a :

```
from PIL import Image
my_image=Image.open("path/to/IMAGE/file")
my_image.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked after I did my_image=Image.open(root.filename) :)